# How to understand if synchronization was started automatically or manually on android?

Tags: android, synchronization, android-syncadapter

I use `SyncAdapter` in my application. So, synchronization can be either automatic ([addPeriodicSync](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#addPeriodicSync%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20long%29)) or started manually ([requestSync](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#requestSync%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29)).

How can I know in the process of synchronization how it was started?
Because, in case it is started manually (from app interface), I would like to show Toasts etc.

Comment: Probably, I can pass some parameter in extras (of both functions). But how can I read that in `SyncAdapter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like usage of extras is the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

Don't Toast to notify your user, except *maybe* for errors or exceptions.  Users already see the circle-arrows "syncing" icon in the Status bar when it's in progress.  I've had apps on my phone that Toast me during sync (every time) and it's annoying as hell...  *Especially* because your users might be using a completely different app when your background sync starts and all of a sudden boom, some random Toast pops up telling them sync is in progress, and they think it comes from the active app, causing confusion.

If you want to show users your sync progress, look instead at this Google IO 2010 presentation: **Developing Android REST
Client Applications** ([pdf](http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-developing-RESTful-android-apps.pdf) and [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE)).  It shows you how to put sync state into rows in your database, and update your UI.  Much better model, as it gives you per-row granularity for information and only shows up if they're looking right at the data being synced.

Comment: I wanted to show Toasts with errors when user started Sync from my application manually. And when it is started automatically, no Toasts should be shown.